# How to change the port which Wekan uses?

Tags: snap, webserver, wekan

By default, Wekan uses `:8080` (the same port is used by, for instance, Syncthing). When changing this port according to the wiki instructions:

```
snap set wekan port='3001'

systemctl restart snap.wekan.wekan
```

...it doesn't actually work. What do I need to do to change the port to say, `:8081`?

I tried this locally, and even disabled my firewall to see if that would be the issue. Wekan still uses the default port.

Comment: Have you looked at Wekan's settings, https://github.com/wekan/wekan/wiki/Settings?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean. Are you trying to connect to this across the net? So, did you enable access to that port on your router and on your server firewall?

Comment: @pbhj It doesn't work as in - it doesn't actually make Wekan use another port. I tried using it locally, although I would like to use it on the web if I could figure out how to get it assigned to a domain name or sub domain. And yes, I tried enabling access on the Firewall (I don't need to do that on the router, and I can't anyway since there's no access to it - thanks to the ISP's set up).

Comment: @LewisM I think so (it's been a while since I last looked at this, but to the best of my memory, I did). I will have to try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to set using root url of Wekan with following

```
sudo snap set wekan root-url="http://localhost:5001"
```

restart your snap of Wekan again

```
sudo systemctl restart snap.wekan.wekan
```

and check your url of Wekan

```
sudo snap get wekan
```

it will appear like

[image]

and sign-in your Wekan on your browser like below

[image]

That's works to me, Hope this helps.